# Angularjs Controller and Expression Behaviour

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm very new to angularjs and going through the tutorials. I'm held up at a point. In the below code why is {{result}} value not being displayed. What is the flow of code in angularjs:

```
<html>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>
   <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">{{ result }}</div>
   <script>
      var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
      app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
         $scope.firstNum = 6;
         $scope.lastNum = 7;
         $scope.result="firstNum*lastNum";
      });
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code http://plnkr.co/edit/oH0gnKExBo9UHmXPuOPS?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

$scope is used for binding the value. You added the multiplication code inside the double quotes that's why it's not working. First of all learn angular using angular tutorials what is directive, scopes, expression etc.

```
<html>    
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
{{ result }}
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.firstNum = 6;
$scope.lastNum = 7;
$scope.result=$scope.firstNum * $scope.lastNum;
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple, you just need to remove quotes `""` and use `$scope` since you declared scope variables.

Since in angularjs everything is related to *scopes*, once you have `$scope` object you can access all the object properties (i.e. declared through scope) can only be accessible via `$scope`

You're doing mathematical operation so there is no significance of using quotes with the initialisation of `$scope.result`.

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.firstNum = 6;
    $scope.lastNum = 7;
    $scope.result= $scope.firstNum * $scope.lastNum; // this change
});
```

[**Updated Plunkr**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/O24v4WebNU5yC7Rp)